why does Spirit not throw an qi::expectation_failure but just parse ok with unparsed lefts?
Its seems that Expectations are only relevant when Spirit already detected that a rule is applicable (from the start) or else the parsing will just fail
It's a simple C-Identifier rule and a Identfier:Identifier rule skipping spaces to show my misunderstanding
Live on Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast
{
    struct Identifier : std::string
    {
    };

    struct A_B
    {
        Identifier a;
        Identifier b;
    };
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Ast::A_B, a, b )

using Iter = std::string_view::const_iterator;

template <typename ValueType, typename RuleType>
void printing_parse_test( const RuleType& rule_, const std::vector<std::string>& tests )
{
    for( std::string_view test : tests )
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing: '" << test << "'\n";
            Iter f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
            // ">> qi::omit[*qi::space]" at end to eat in-between rest spaces ...
            ValueType v;
            const bool ok = qi::parse( f, l, rule_ >> qi::omit[*qi::space], v );
            std::cout << "parse-result: " << ( ok ? "ok" : "failed" ) << "\n";
            const std::string left( f, l );
            if( ok )
            {
                if( !left.empty() )
                {
                    std::cout << "FAIL: parsed someway but left this '" << left << "'\n ";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "OK: all parsed\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( !left.empty() )
                {
                    std::cout << "FAIL: parse failed left this: '" << left << "'\n";
                }
            }
        }
        catch( qi::expectation_failure<Iter> const& ef )
        {
            auto f = begin( test );
            auto p = ef.first - test.begin();
            auto bol = test.find_last_of( "\r\n", p ) + 1;
            auto line = std::count( f, f + bol, '\n' ) + 1;
            auto eol = test.find_first_of( "\r\n", p );

            std::cout << " -> EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << " col:" << ( p - bol ) << "\n"
                      << test.substr( bol, eol - bol ) << "\n"
                      << std::setw( p - bol ) << ""
                      << "^--- here" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "--------------------\n";
    }
    std::cout << "============\n";
}

int main()
{
    qi::rule<Iter, Ast::Identifier()> identifier_rule = qi::char_( "a-zA-Z_" ) > *qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" );
    identifier_rule.name( "identifier_rule" );
    printing_parse_test<Ast::Identifier>( identifier_rule, { "  test blib ", "", "23434", "a$", "test blub" } );

    qi::rule<Iter, Ast::A_B()> A_B_rule = qi::skip( qi::space )[( identifier_rule > ":" > identifier_rule )];
    A_B_rule.name( "A_B_rule" );
    printing_parse_test<Ast::A_B>( A_B_rule, { "e$:bd", "a", "", "23434", "a$", "a:$" } );

    return 0;
}

Output:
Parsing: '  test blib '
parse-result: failed
FAIL: parse failed left this: '  test blib '
--------------------
Parsing: ''
parse-result: failed
--------------------
Parsing: '23434'
parse-result: failed
FAIL: parse failed left this: '23434'
--------------------
Parsing: 'a$'
parse-result: ok
FAIL: parsed someway but left this '$'
 --------------------
Parsing: 'test blub'
parse-result: ok
FAIL: parsed someway but left this 'blub'
 --------------------
============
Parsing: 'e$:bd'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
e$:bd
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
a
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: ''
parse-result: failed
--------------------
Parsing: '23434'
parse-result: failed
FAIL: parse failed left this: '23434'
--------------------
Parsing: 'a$'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
a$
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a:$'
 -> EXPECTED <identifier_rule> in line:1 col:2
a:$
  ^--- here
--------------------
============

Expectation:
why do i not get an EXPECTED <identifier_rule> when parsing '23434', or empty string etc. with both rules?
isn't my expectation that the string starts with an identifier? how can i archive that
or is that something that will be a problem when combining my rules later?
and an additional question is why "a$" results only in ':' expected not the additional information that also identifier literals are ok (or is that more of an hint?)

You already correctly found the way to cause an expectation point.
You can further simplify by using a skipper and qi::eoi to check that all input is consumed. I'd suggest the simplified listing:
Live On Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct Identifier : std::string {};
    struct QualifiedId { Identifier a, b; };
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::QualifiedId, a, b)

using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;

template <typename Attr, typename Skipper>
void run_tests(qi::rule<It, Attr(), Skipper> const& rule_, std::vector<std::string> const& tests) {
    std::cout << "======[ " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(Attr).name()) << " ]======" << std::endl;
    for (std::string_view test : tests) {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        try {
            std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted(test);
            Attr  v;
            bool  ok;

            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Skipper, qi::unused_type>)
                ok = qi::parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, v);
            else
                ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, Skipper{}, v);

            std::cout << (ok ? "OK" : "FAIL") << " Remaining: " << quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
        } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& ef) {
            auto p    = ef.first - test.begin();
            auto bol  = test.find_last_of("\r\n", p) + 1;
            auto line = std::count(f, f + bol, '\n') + 1;
            auto eol  = test.find_first_of("\r\n", p);

            std::cout << " -> EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << " col:" << (p - bol) << "\n"
                      << "    " << test.substr(bol, eol - bol) << "\n"
                      << "    " << std::setw(p - bol) << "" << "^--- here\n";
        }
        std::cout << "--------------------\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier()>                  id = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
    qi::rule<It, Ast::QualifiedId(), qi::space_type> qualId = qi::eps > id > ":" > id;
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((id)(qualId))

    run_tests(id, {"  test blib ", "", "23434", "a$", "test blub"});
    run_tests(qualId, {"e$:bd", "a", "", "23434", "a$", "a:$"});
}

Which prints

======[ Ast::Identifier ]======
Parsing: "  test blib " -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:0
      test blib 
    ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "" -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:0
    
    ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "23434" -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:0
    23434
    ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "a$" -> EXPECTED <eoi> in line:1 col:1
    a$
     ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "test blub" -> EXPECTED <eoi> in line:1 col:4
    test blub
        ^--- here
--------------------
======[ Ast::QualifiedId ]======
Parsing: "e$:bd" -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
    e$:bd
     ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "a" -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
    a
     ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "" -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:0
    
    ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "23434" -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:0
    23434
    ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "a$" -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
    a$
     ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "a:$" -> EXPECTED <id> in line:1 col:2
    a:$
      ^--- here
--------------------


thank for cleaning up my example - always tiny bits to learn from your posts

qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") is the same as
qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") > *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") here? >> vs > - having expectations points that can be zero is someway strange but not wrong in my example, or?

Precisely 

found it
qi::eps

is the answer - this way i've got a expected sequence right from the start
const bool ok = qi::parse( f, l, qi::eps > rule_ >> qi::omit[*qi::space], v );

gives me the execption also on start
Output
Parsing: '  test blib '
 -> EXPECTED <identifier_rule> in line:1 col:0
  test blib
^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: ''
 -> EXPECTED <identifier_rule> in line:1 col:0

^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: '23434'
 -> EXPECTED <identifier_rule> in line:1 col:0
23434
^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a$'
parse-result: ok
FAIL: parsed someway but left this '$'
 --------------------
Parsing: 'test blub'
parse-result: ok
FAIL: parsed someway but left this 'blub'
 --------------------
============
Parsing: 'e$:bd'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
e$:bd
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
a
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: ''
 -> EXPECTED <A_B_rule> in line:1 col:0

^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'x 23434'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:2
x 23434
  ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a$'
 -> EXPECTED ":" in line:1 col:1
a$
 ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: 'a:$'
 -> EXPECTED <identifier_rule> in line:1 col:2
a:$
  ^--- here
--------------------
============


Yes. Technically, your answer is completely wrong. qi::eps doesn't do a thing (literally). It's operator> that creates the expectation point (which is the only thing it does other than operator>>): expectation operator. But yeah, this is the way. Spirit X3 lets you explicitly use the directive: x3::expect[ expr ]

Technically, your answer is completely wrong.
not fully - i stated that it makes my sequence "starts" earlier - qi::eps isn't doing something on its own

I was unnecessarily harsh. Though I expect just people to read it that way initially. Yes the way you applied it is correct

time to dry up my tears :)
